# Cors Issue with React Frontend and Django Backend

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, cross-domain

So I have build backend API in Django with inbuilt user module for authentication login etc.

The login API return Set Cookie in Response header when correct user and pass is passed.(Tested in Postman and works fine)

However when fetch function is called in reactJS, it's not setting Cookie in browser to be used later on further requests.

Django CORS Setting.

```
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["django-env-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", "*","127.0.0.1"]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'https://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "127.0.0.1:3000",
    "localhost:3000",
]
```

Django API which return and Set-Cookie in  response header

```
def signin(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            
            user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
            print(str(user))
            
            
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                fname = user.first_name
                # messages.success(request, "Logged In Sucessfully!!")
                sessionid=request.session.session_key
                return JsonResponse({"Status":"Success","session":sessionid})
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Bad Credentials!!")
                return JsonResponse({"Status":"Bad Credentials!!"},status=401)
        
        return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return("Crashed")
```

React Fetch Code

```
   var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("username", `${users.username}`);
    urlencoded.append("password", `${users.password}`);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow',
      credentials: "include"

 };
 

//Fetching Login api
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/authentication/signin", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => handleResult(JSON.parse(data)))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

Once Cookie is set in browser using below Code to pass Cookie in a new API Call. (But this is failing currently since Cookie is not set in request header as well)

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
      let requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        credentials: "include"
      }; 
  
//Calling ME api
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/authentication/me", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => handleData(JSON.parse(result)))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Could you put the code that set the cookie in django side, please?
And when you test your api with Postman or CURL, you can see the cookie?

Comment: @Jony_23 added API code as well. And yes I can see set-cookie in Response Headers

Comment: Sorry @Lakshya Kumar, but I don't see any part of code where you set the cookie. You only return a message and a session id inside the JSON response, but that isn't a cookie.

You to take a Response object and make `response.set_cookie(**attrs_cookie)`. For example: `response.set_cookie(settings.AUTH_COOKIE # Key , refresh  #and value, max_age=time_cookie, domain=settings.COOKIE_DOMAIN, path='/', samesite='Strict', secure=True, httponly=True)`
You can read more of this in [HttpResponse Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects).

Comment: @Jony_23 as far as I know, Cookie is set by auth module by Django itself. Hence its being set when I call authenticate function. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right. However, I think you you have code it like I wrote in my last comment, because if you notice, in that part you set the domain to which the cookie is intended and also the option configure the 'samesite', the 'path' where is visible, if it will be readable just by HTTP, etc.
I have just read that you can configure all that with [Django Session settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#sessions), maybe you only have to set this options.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set the `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` setting. As mentioned in django-cors-headers' [GitHub repo](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_credentials-bool):

> If `True`, cookies will be allowed to be included in cross-site HTTP
> requests. Defaults to `False`.

Specifying this would would set the [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) header allowing the browser to expose the cookies to JavaScript.

Hence you need to add the following to your settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: I think you missed it. But its already set in Django settings. However added SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE aswell but no luck.